# how to copy files from one location to another if name of that file exists in an Excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file that contains the names of the image files. In the same folder, I have all the images listed in the Excel file plus some additional images. Now what I want to do is to separate all the images which are listed in the Excel file. The images that are enlisted in the Excel file should be copied to another folder. I have used the method as instructed by the author of this post:

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4775-move-files-based-on-excel-list.html

```
Sub movefiles()
'Updateby Extendoffice
    Dim xRg As Range, xCell As Range
    Dim xSFileDlg As FileDialog, xDFileDlg As FileDialog
    Dim xSPathStr As Variant, xDPathStr As Variant
    Dim xVal As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the file names:", "KuTools For Excel", ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address, , , , , 8)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set xSFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xSFileDlg.Title = " Please select the original folder:"
    If xSFileDlg.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    xSPathStr = xSFileDlg.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
    Set xDFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xDFileDlg.Title = " Please select the destination folder:"
    If xDFileDlg.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    xDPathStr = xDFileDlg.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
    For Each xCell In xRg
        xVal = xCell.Value
        If TypeName(xVal) = "String" And xVal <> "" Then
            FileCopy xSPathStr & xVal, xDPathStr & xVal
            Kill xSPathStr & xVal
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

but when I execute the code nothing happens. Is there any way to do the task?

Comment: I have updated the question and included the code as well. @BigBen

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next` and rerun. Do you get an error and on what line and what's the error message?

Comment: Runtime Error '53':
File Not Found

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your file names to be honest